# Same space between 2 inputText boxes using JSF and CSS

Tags: css, jsf

I want to create a JSF form where users can write their name and surname and validate them using JSF validators. The problem is that I would like to set the same space between the 2 inputText boxes in the form, in both cases, when the typed data is correct according to the validator, and when it is not correct. So if between the 2 inputText boxes there are X pixels if the user has not typed anything, when typed name is not correct, the error showing message should be displayed between the 2 inputText boxes and the pixels between them should be also X px. I suppose this is a CSS issue, but I am unable to get it, so any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code

```
<h:form>
                <p:panel id="panelregister">
                <h:panelGrid columns="1">

                    <!--Name-->
                    <p:inputText id="name" label="name" size="32" maxlength="9"
                             value="#{mManagedBean.name}">              
                    <f:validator validatorId="packagevalidators.NameValidator"/> 
                    </p:inputText>
                    <p:watermark for="name" value="Name (*)" />
                    <p:message for="name"/>




                    <!--Surname-->
                    <p:inputText id="surname" label="surname" required="true" size="32" maxlength="9"
                            value="#{mManagedBean.surname}"
                            requiredMessage="Must enter a surname">              
                        <f:validator validatorId="packagevalidators.SurnameValidator"/> 
                   </p:inputText>
                   <p:watermark for="surname" value="Surname (*)" />
                   <p:message for="surname" />

                 <p:commandButton value="Submit" action="#{mManagedBean.save}" ajax="false" />
                 </h:panelGrid>
                 </p:panel>
             </h:form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `h:panelGrid` which renders as HTML `<table>`.
`p:message` will be rendered as `div` and by default that `div` won't have any content so it won't take any space you provide.
One way to do this is to use a `h:panelGroup` around it and give pre defined height of `p:message`
Example:

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" style="height:27px">
    <p:message for="name" />
</h:panelGroup>
```